# Experiencing "unknown column" following N per parent in hasMany() tweak

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm currently trying this tweak to get N posts per relation, e.g. 5 comments for each post, instead of 5 comments of the total posts (The issue).

The tweak is provided [here](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/) and mentioned in many answers on SO.

My model is pretty simple. I've copied the `BaseModel` and defined the namespace for it. After that, I included the tweak in the relation like this:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DismaUserComment::class, 'parent_comment_id', "id")}
                ->where("visible", 1)
                ->orderBy("created_at", "ASC");
}

public function repliesLimited()
{
    return $this->replies()->latest()->nPerGroup('reply_comment_id', 5);
}
```

In the Controller, I'm calling `with('repliesLimited')`. The exception that I'm getting is:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(select `app_users_comments`.*, @rank := IF(@group = reply_comment_id, @rank+1, 1)' in 'field list' (SQL: select ```` (select ``app_users_comments```. ````*, @rank := IF(@group = reply_comment_id, @rank+1, 1)`as`rank_807a5773f971e6e6a9db9e1d6ef4f63a, @group := reply_comment_id`, (select count(*) from`app_users_comments_votes`where`app_users_comments`.`id`=`app_users_comments_votes`.`comment_id`) as`votes_count`, (select count(*) from`app_users_comments_votes`where`app_users_comments`.`id`=`app_users_comments_votes`.`comment_id`and`vote_type`= 1) as`upvotes_count`, (select count(*) from`app_users_comments_votes`where`app_users_comments`.`id`=`app_users_comments_votes`.`comment_id`and`vote_type`= 0) as`downvotes_count`from (select`app_users_comments`.*, @rank := IF(@group = reply_comment_id, @rank+1, 1) as rank_807a5773f971e6e6a9db9e1d6ef4f63a, @group := reply_comment_id as group_807a5773f971e6e6a9db9e1d6ef4f63a from (SELECT @rank:=0, @group:=0) as vars, app_users_comments where`visible`= 1 and`app_users_comments`.`deleted_at`is null order by`reply_comment_id`asc,`created_at`asc,`created_at`desc) as app_users_comments where`rank_807a5773f971e6e6a9db9e1d6ef4f63a`<= 5 and`app_users_comments`.`parent_comment_id`in (1, 12, 13) and`app_users_comments`.`deleted_at` is null)"

Desired output:

Get 5 posts (already done) 
for each post, there should be 2 comments.

The basic way is to limit the relation, but this will return only 2 comments of the whole comments relation, instead of 2 comments PER post.

Comment: Could you provide further information about your desired output? You mentioned that post, but how about explaining what the post intended to do? Maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: I've created a package that implements this kind of query: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Comment: Hello, I've commented on your library. Kindly check the issue.

Comment: @HCK I've added it at the end.

Comment: Dunno if it's a typo or not but there's a bracket (`}`) in your replies() method.that doesn't look like it belongs there. At the end of the first line.

Comment: It's a typo, I apologize.

Comment: I know nothing about that package but you could simply eager load N replies per post by combining  the `each()` and `load()` methods, provided posts are paginated to avoid making too many queries.